# isearch across line breaks

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to make isearch disregard line breaks, i.e. a search for `foo bar` will find

```
.......... foo
bar .....
```

I get bitten by isearch failing on such queries regularly when navigating long documents, and it's rather annoying.  I am aware that `word-search-forward` finds matches across lines, but it has certain shortcomings (e.g. it forces you to use complete words, so a search for "foo b" will fail; it doesn't highlight search results), and, more importantly, it's a little silly to use a different command depending on whether you are searching for one word or two.

Comment: It might be useful in many cases to ensure line breaks are cosmetic in Emacs.  Use `global-visual-line-mode` to wrap lines without affecting buffer contents.  If there is an actual carriage return across lines, well, that seems like it should be something you would have to search for, since it is a paragraph break or a new statement in the program code, for example.

Comment: It _might_ be useful, however it's hardly standard practice.  In particular, I have never come across a LaTeX document without hard CRs. May I remind you that both `global-visual-line-mode` and `longlines-mode` which preceded it are fairly young by emacs standards?  Lots of legacy documents to deal with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>C-M-s</kbd> - isearch-forward-regexp.  This will interpret space characters as a marker for any white space character.

Comment: This works.  Maybe I'll start using regexp isearch instead of regular isearch then... Note that you also need to customize `search-whitespace-regexp` (see `C-h v search-whitespace-regexp` for details).

Comment: I find that I don't need to use `isearch-forward-regexp` in order to obtain the desired behaviour once I customise `search-whitespace-regexp` to something like `[ \t\r\n]+` as suggested in the documentation.  It is enough to use `search-forward` as usual.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill Please add an answer with this information.

Answer (score 4):

As prompted by @Teddy, here’s my comment in answer form.

In order to obtain the desired behaviour, I did not have to customise `isearch-forward-regexp`, but simply customise `search-whitespace-regexp` to `[ \t\r\n]+`as suggested in the documentation.  This way you can then use `search-forward` as usual.

Comment: That alone did not work for me. The solution here did. (Maybe because I am using a newer Emacs version?) http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/search-for-string-ignoring-new-lines

Answer (score 1):

In a recent enough emacs, `isearch-forward-word`, which is bound to `M-s w`, is a simpler solution: there is no need for any configuration of `search-whitespace-regexp`.